# /etc/resolv.conf order not respected by `ping`

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

CentOS 7. My problem is a seemingly common issue where `nslookup` can resolve a host, but `ping` can't. However, the common answers like messing with [avahi or /etc/nsswitch.conf](https://superuser.com/questions/704785/ping-cant-resolve-hostname-but-nslookup-can) don't help because my VPS is running neither Avahi nor NetworkManager.  (in other words, I can break `/etc/nsswitch.conf` by setting `hosts: files` and `ping` continues to work)

`/etc/resolv.conf` is as follows:

```
nameserver 10.44.13.246
nameserver 10.32.72.88
nameserver 10.32.72.86
```

Where the first nameserver points to an instance of `dnsmasq` that's running on another of my VPSes, and the last two are the hosting provider's DNS servers. I expect them to be queried in order (the last two are simply last-resort fallbacks).

Now, for any of the hosts defined in that `dnsmasq` instance, `nslookup` always works, and `ping` works *some of the time* -- a host will resolve properly, then break, then a few minutes later it will be fine again. However, if I remove the upstream DNS servers in `etc/resolv.conf` like this,

```
nameserver 10.44.13.246
#nameserver 10.32.72.88
#nameserver 10.32.72.86
```

then `ping` immediately starts to work *100% of the time*. This directly contradicts the resolv.conf docs, which say that in the absence of an `option rotate` directive, the servers are queried in order until one sends a response.

`nscd` is running and is being hit, because I can see the cache hit/miss counters go up for these problematic queries.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: use `strace` to see what's happening.

Comment: @Hanginoninquietdesperation great idea. Nothing surprising about ping/getent, but nscd shows suspiciously little activity when there's a name resolution failure. Will dig in more there.

Answer (score 9):

I don't have a direct answer to the larger question but answers for some distinct parts of it.

**Regarding `ping` vs `nslookup`**

It's worth noting that `ping` is just an example of a regular program which uses the OS resolver library (ie, `getaddrinfo`/`gethostbyname` calls) while `nslookup` (as well as `dig`, etc) are DNS client programs making DNS queries of their own, rather than using the resolver library, they just so happen to pick up their default server from the configuration file for the system resolver as a matter of convenience.

What this means is that `nslookup` is bad for testing how the system resolver behaves (ie `resolv.conf`, `nsswitch.conf`, etc), while eg `ping` is bad for testing DNS.

It can be noted that in Linux-land I would consider `getent ahosts` (eg `getent ahosts www.example.com`) a better choice for testing the resolver behavior, and `dig` to be much preferrable over `nslookup` for testing DNS.

**Regarding what you can do to see what is happening**

As was suggested by *Hangin on in quiet desperation*, you may want to use `strace` (maybe also `ltrace` for a higher level view) and I would suggest using it with `getent ahosts` rather than `ping` to not get all the noise of what is `ping`'s actual purpose, while you're trying to observe what is just a side-effect. `getent ahosts` just does this one thing that you're trying to investigate.

**Regarding what to have in resolv.conf**

What you're saying about things "breaking" when the "wrong" server is queried makes me wonder why you are putting all of those servers in `resolv.conf` in the first place. It's generally really not a good idea to put servers with different behavior (different in some way that is actually significant to your use) all in the list.

Comment: I'm with you on dig/getent vs. nslookup/ping. I didn't know about getent, and I'll make sure all my machines have dig from now on (force of habit to use nslookup).

And agreed about your last point. I guess the correct solution is likely to run at least two instances of dnsmasq in my environment and remove upstream servers from other machines.

Answer (score 0):

Ping is old. It predates nsswitch, and uses a file /etc/host.conf (not sure if this is still relevant to RHEL7)

Also, you won't be consulting /etc/hosts: might I suggest you try `getent hosts name.example.com`, which will consult /etc/hosts (as configured by nsswitch.conf). This uses the standard name resolving functionality of the C library, where `host` (and `dig`) are expressly just about DNS, and only look at /etc/resolv.conf to set defaults for things like which nameservers and search domain to use—but otherwise use part of the BIND DNS software code to query DNS